# In a test I can find a xml, in another I can't

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have an interesting problem, I have two web services defined in a spring-conf.xml file and I have two test classes that live in the same package and every class has its own link to this spring-conf.xml file to call their particular webservice.
I am able to get beans from one of my test classes but from the other one I can't and the code is equal in both classes.

In one I have this

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class WSFirstTest {

private ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "WEB-INF/spring-conf.xml");
private WSFirst ws = (WSFirst) context
        .getBean("serviceFirstDefault");
```

in the other one I have this

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class WSSecondTest {

private ApplicationContext context2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "WEB-INF/spring-conf.xml");
private WSSecond ws = (WSSecond) context2
        .getBean("serviceSecondDefault");
```

In the second one my program can't find the spring-conf file, but in the other one is able.
What's the problem?

PS Both wservices work fine when I call them from remote, only in local I have this problem.

The test's error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/spring-conf.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring-conf.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Thank you for your advises.

Comment: Are those JUnit tests running in parallel?

Comment: yes, exactly. I run them with junit one by one, individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know Spring interprets an application context path without starting "/" as a **relative path** from the same package in which the test class is defined and pathes with starting "/" as **fully qualified class path locations** (at least in the [testing environment](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management)). Maybe you should try to use a starting "/".

It turned out that different test run configurations caused the problem (see comments below).

Comment: thank you for your answer. no, this isn't the point, because the comportaments are different and they depend on what test I launch, the paths are identical and both classes are in the same package, but one can find my file and the other can't. because they are situated in the same location as I said the paths must be identical. anyway I tried what you said but it didn't work

Comment: @Tommaso Bicego How do you run the tests? Maybe there are differences in your run configuration (classpath, etc.).

Comment: you are a genius. I looked a moment ago in my run configurations and in the first configuration there was my WebContent folder and in the other there wasn't. I add it to the other run configuration and now the run works perfectly. Thank you!